# Обрезается и/или не отображается нижняя часть фонового изображения

Tags: css, wordpress, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, background-image

На планшете и смартфоне отображается плавно, а на десктопе в HD, FullHD нижняя часть "обрезается". Код привести не могу, так как его много, а где кроется суть не знаю. Если менять масштаб в браузере линия бывает прямой.
[image: На пк]

[image: На планшете]

Сам сайт https://suik.online/

С уважением

Comment: Можете сделать `background-position: bottom`, тогда низ обрезаться не будет, но возможно иногда будет обрезаться этот Ваш кружочек.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо держать соотношение сторон div, в котором фоновая картинка. Тогда обрезаться не будет.

```
.et_pb_fullwidth_header.et_pb_fullwidth_header_0 {
    height: 56.25vw;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position